# Virtualize 3070 For Ubuntu VM and Win 11 Host

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, gpu-passthrough

I am using Hyper-V as my hypervisor and would like to virtualize my 3070 and pass it to the Ubuntu VM.

Is it possible to do this without DDA? From what I have read, DDA gives the entire GPU to the VM and the host has to use another GPU.

In my case, this would be fine since I have an igpu but it's not ideal. I would like the VM and the host to use 3070 at the same time. One example of this use case is gaming on the host while light AI training is happing on vm

Comment: Both operating systems using a device at once is not "virtualizing the GPU". Non-Datacenter GPUs don't have virtualized functions, eher you can hand in "parts" of the device to iommu groups, and even those that do are not the kind of GPU that comes with a port that you can plug a screen into.